# ¿Cómo selecciono valores de un data frame de múltiples columnas?

Tags: r

Tengo un data.frame (`prob2`) de 5000 filas y 1300 columnas. Quisiera extraer todos aquellos valores `<=0.023` de todas las columnas.
Con el siguiente código puedo extraer los valores que cumplen la condición para la primera columna, pero cómo aplico esto a todas las columnas?

```
prob2[prob2$site_103000262 <= 0.023,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto lo puedes hacer usando distintas variaciones de la función `filter` de la librería `dplyr`. Sería ideal si puedes compartir una muestra de la data, para replicar esto.

```
# Opción 1
prob2 %>% filter(across(c(1:1300), ~ . <=0.023))

# Opción 2
prob2 %>% filter_all(any_vars(. <=0.023))
```

Answer (score 0):

Una solución R base sería:

```
prob2[rowSums(apply(prob2, 2, `<=`, .023)) > 0, ]
```

Detalle:

- Con `apply()` aplicamos la comparación a nivel de fila
- Sumamos los valores `TRUE` por fila
- Si la suma de estos es mayor a 0 seleccionamos la fila